# How to apply patches for Magento 1.x in Windows?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, magento-1.6, windows

I don't know how to update patches for magento. I tried cygwin in Windows but without success:

[image]

Can anybody help me to solve these problems?

Comment: Your question and tag is contradicting. In question you've mentioned magento2 and in tags there is magento-1.9.

Comment: sr i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

To get patches for Magento CE:

- Log in to magentocommerce.com/download.
  (Click My Account in the upper right corner of the page.)
  If you don't have an account, you can register for one; the account is free.
- In the Magento Community Edition Patches section, locate the patch to install.
- From the list next to the patch, choose your CE version.
- Click Download.
- After the patch downloads, continue with applying these patches.

To apply a Magento patch:

- Transfer the patch .sh file to your Magento installation root directory.
- Enter the following command as a user with sufficient privileges to write to Magento files (typically, the web server user or root):

  `sh patch-file-name.sh`

  A message such as the following displays to confirm the patch installed successfully:

  `Patch was applied/reverted successfully.`

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

Comment: when i run `sh PATCH_SUPEE-2677.sh` it return 
`'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

So i tried install cygwin. u can see image in my question.

Comment: I think this could solve your problem: http://superuser.com/questions/820674/running-sh-exe-in-windows-cmd-exe-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the patch file is not set to executable. To fix that, run first:

```
chmod +x ./PATCH_SUPEE......
```

or pass it to bash instead:

```
bash ./PATCH_SUPEE.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a Linux inspired shell in windows

For example find git for windows online

Use the bundled shell that comes with it.

> Git for Windows provides a BASH emulation used to run Git from the command line. *NIX users should feel right at home, as the BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX environments.

Then you should be able to execute patch files as per docs